# Some areas of label repeat, do not show, or appear offsets in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, labeling, sld

I found that tile map of each region in geoserver2.9.2 of platform independent binary displays its name two or more times. As shown in the first picture.

I have done as [How to avoid duplicate labels on each tile? [duplicate]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29127/how-to-avoid-duplicate-labels-on-each-tile) and [Polygon label repeated for each tile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37138/polygon-label-repeated-for-each-tile). However, some areas of label in sixth and seventh level do not show and some appear offsets. As shown in the second picture.

Here's my code:

```
<TextSymbolizer>
 <Geometry>
  <ogc:Function name="centroid">
     <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
  </ogc:Function>
 </Geometry>
</TextSymbolizer>
```

And then I have done as [Labels on tiled map sometimes unavailable](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156904/labels-on-tiled-map-sometimes-unavailable). It was same as above in seventh level.

Here's my code:

```
<VendorOption name="partials">true</VendorOption>
```

I have no idea how to modify it. Can anybody tell me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This questions looks somewhat familiar....

Comment: What version of geoserver are you using?

Comment: The version of geoserver is 2.9.2 of platform independent binary. I asked this question a few days ago. And someone gave me a similar problem of links, which did not solve my problem.

Comment: Do you got the CSS Plugin? You might try recreating the style with CSS.

Comment: I closed this last time because it is a duplicate - please edit your other question if you think it isn't a duplicate.